# Getting audio file from a UDP packet

Tags: python, networking, udp, hex, wireshark

Posting this here out of desperation. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Backstory:

I am helping my friend with a device that he got from China. The device supposedly sends a audio file to my server using UDP.

Comment: _0000cf6c_ looks like a hex value and it's equal to 53100 (53.1 KB). To get the whole data you need all packets (I think the data above is only one packet). You also need to capture the whole packet (`-s0` using _tcpdump_ - not sure about wireshark).

Comment: Thank you for replying! For some reason this is the only packet that it sends me. I'll continue playing with it and see what I can get

Comment: the device might be expecting confirmation that the packet has been received before sending more data.  maybe check the docs you've got to see if there's anything else

Comment: @SamMason I literally just tried this out after the previous comment! I sent a confirmation back after each packet was sent to the server and got like 50 packets in total each of 911 bytes according to wireshark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you want some Python code to do this automatically, here's how I'd validate and decode the packet:

```
import struct

def decode_packet(packet):
    framehead, version, command, datalen = struct.unpack_from('!HBBH', packet)

    valid = (
        framehead == 0x55aa and
        version == 0x00 and
        command == 0x1e and
        len(packet) <= datalen + 11
    )
    if not valid:
        # ignore other protocols using this address/port
        print(
            '  header invalid',
            f'{framehead:04x} {version:02x} {command:02x} {datalen:04x}'
        )
        return

    if len(packet) < datalen + 11:
        print('  warning: packet was truncated')

    offset, = struct.unpack_from('!I', packet, 6)
    if datalen == 4:
        print(f'  end of data: file size={offset}')
        return

    data = packet[10:10+datalen]
    print(f'  got data: offset={offset} len={len(data)} hex(data)={data.hex()}')

    if len(packet) == datalen + 11:
        print(f'  hex(checksum)={packet[datalen + 10:].hex()}')
```

it obviously prints out a lot of stuff, but this is good to seeing if the device is actually following the documented protocol.  it doesn't seem to be, as the `+4` on the `data length` doesn't seem to be being applied.  you can test this with:

```
decode_packet(bytes.fromhex('55aa001e038400000000a9b6ad98d2923...'))
```

assuming you can get this to function correctly, you can put this into some code that listens for packets on the correct port:

```
import socket

def server(portnum):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
        sock.bind(('', portnum))

        while True:
            packet, addr = sock.recvfrom(10240)
            print(f'received {len(packet)} bytes from {addr[0]}')
            decode_packet(packet)
```

again, doesn't do much.  you'd want to write the data to a file rather than printing it out, but you can pull the offset out and you get a signal for when the data has finished transferring

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will look through the code. I just quickly wanted to ask why you used sock.recvfrom(10240)? I am currently using sock.recvfrom(4096) following an example that I saw online

Comment: I don't think the actual value matters as long as it's bigger than any packet you expect to receive.  jumbo-packets can be 9000 bytes, and 10KiB is the next nicest round number after this...  that said, anything more than 1500 is probably fine (the limit for ethernet)

Comment: note that you don't want to pass anything too crazy, e.g. 128MiB! a buffer of that size will be allocated (and then resized when less data is received) but it's probably fine here

Comment: So if I want to write these bytes that are received to a file, I would need to write to a binary file? How do I save the incoming bytes and convert to an audio file?

Comment: as far as writing, it's just the standard `open(name, 'wb')`, `seek(offset)` and `write(data)`, nothing special needed.  you'd need to figure out format of the data in order to play it back, hopefully that's documented somewhere, it can be pretty awkward to reverse engineer!

Comment: Looks like you are right! I finally got this code working on python 3.6. Was previously trying to run with python 2.x which is why it did not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201980/discussion-between-user3702643-and-sam-mason).