# Removing first few bytes from UDP packet using python

Tags: python, websocket, udp, hex, packet

From WireShark I can see that a UDP packet is being sent to my server containing data that I need.

Raw packet data from wireshark:

```
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
```

Using python, how do I remove the first 20 characters:

```
55aa001e03840000c864
```

and save the rest?

Current code:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 8484)
sock.bind(server_address)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address

while True:
    print('\nwaiting to receive message')
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(10240)
```

Comment: as per your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58725656/1358308), you just need to remove 10 bytes (when hex encoded this expands to 20 hex digits).  you also need to ignore the checksum digit at the end.  also note that packets can get truncated, so you probably need to check for that as well.  the code in my last response checked for and did this...

Answer (score 0):

Since the within the `data` variable is of type `bytes`, which I think can be translated to something like `b'<string_with_your_packet_data>'`, I think you can use slicing just as you would do on a standard string and it should work just fine.

So something among the lines of

```
while True:
    print('\nwaiting to receive message')
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(10240)
    sliced_packet = data[20:]  # trimming your first 20 characters from your data
```

Comment: Thank you! Would I be able to print out sliced_packet to see if it worked?

Comment: sure, that should work and you should be able to test your output and changes